# im trying to put my matplotlib animation into a GUI

Tags: python, matplotlib, user-interface, pysimplegui

As the title says, I am trying to put my matplotlib animation into a GUI however, im not too sure where to start. I am very much new to python, especially using it to make GUIs. Right now this is what I have for my animation:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

points = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
xfixdata, yfixdata = 15,10
xdata, ydata = 5, None
ln, = plt.plot([], [], 'ro-', animated=True)
plt.plot([xfixdata], [yfixdata], 'bo', ms=10)

def init():
    ax.set_xlim(0, 20)
    ax.set_ylim(0, 20)
    return ln,

def update(frame):
    ydata = points[frame]
    ln.set_data([xfixdata,xdata], [yfixdata,ydata])
    return ln,


ani = FuncAnimation(fig, update, interval=80, frames=range(len(points)),
            init_func=init, blit=True)
plt.show()
```

Right now, I've been attempting to transfer this code into a canvas using pysimpleGUI however, I am not making any progress. Is there any chance that one of you could somewhat walk me through the process of converting this? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one demo code for you about the matplotlib animation in PySimpleGUI `Graph` element, of course, you can use `Canvas` element

```py
import math

from matplotlib import use as use_agg
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import PySimpleGUI as sg

def pack_figure(graph, figure):
    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(figure, graph.Widget)
    plot_widget = canvas.get_tk_widget()
    plot_widget.pack(side='top', fill='both', expand=1)
    return plot_widget

def plot_figure(index, theta):
    fig = plt.figure(index)         # Active an existing figure
    ax = plt.gca()                  # Get the current axes
    x = [degree for degree in range(1080)]
    y = [math.sin((degree+theta)/180*math.pi) for degree in range(1080)]
    ax.cla()                        # Clear the current axes
    ax.set_title(f"Sensor Data {index}")
    ax.set_xlabel("X axis")
    ax.set_ylabel("Y axis")
    ax.set_xscale('log')
    ax.grid()
    plt.plot(x, y)                  # Plot y versus x as lines and/or markers
    fig.canvas.draw()               # Rendor figure into canvas

# Use Tkinter Agg
use_agg('TkAgg')

layout = [[sg.Graph((640, 480), (0, 0), (640, 480), key='Graph1'), sg.Graph((640, 480), (0, 0), (640, 480), key='Graph2')]]
window = sg.Window('Matplotlib', layout, finalize=True)


# Initial
graph1 = window['Graph1']
graph2 = window['Graph2']
plt.ioff()                          # Turn the interactive mode off
fig1 = plt.figure(1)                # Create a new figure
ax1 = plt.subplot(111)              # Add a subplot to the current figure.
fig2 = plt.figure(2)                # Create a new figure
ax2 = plt.subplot(111)              # Add a subplot to the current figure.
pack_figure(graph1, fig1)           # Pack figure under graph
pack_figure(graph2, fig2)
theta1 = 0                          # theta for fig1
theta2 = 90                         # theta for fig2
plot_figure(1, theta1)
plot_figure(2, theta2)

while True:

    event, values = window.read(timeout=10)

    if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event == sg.TIMEOUT_EVENT:
        theta1 = (theta1 + 40) % 360
        plot_figure(1, theta1)
        theta2 = (theta2 + 40) % 260
        plot_figure(2, theta2)

window.close()
```